# Why is it illegal to have var inside an if() expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript

At least in V8 something like

```
if((var i = x*x) == 2){}
```

will give an error about an unexpected 'var' keyword. However there is no error if the var happens before the if() but I still leave the assignment of i in the expression. Why such an odd exception? Is this in the ECMA script standard somewhere? Is there a undetectable closure happening within the evaluation of the if() expression so leaving in the var would make my assignment disappear?

To further generalize it appears that `var` must have no non-white space characters preceding it.

Comment: This seems to be because `var` is a keyword in the ECMA-262 standard that is used to identify a VariableStatement, which is a statement and not an expression.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that you can't use a variable statement as the expression to evaluate in an if.

A more detailed answer is that according to ECMA-262 s12.5, an if statement has the form:

```
if ( Expression) Statement else Statement
```

ECMA-262 s11 describes an Expression as:

```
PrimaryExpression :
  this
  Identifier
  Literal
  ArrayLiteral
  ObjectLiteral
  ( Expression )
```

An expression that starts with `var` is a VariableStatment (ECMA-262 s12.2), which is not one of the above.